# What's the ROI of Sub-Repositories?

Tags: mercurial, roi, subrepos

I know that sub-repositories save you an your team time, but what is the ROI on them?

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/subrepos

Comment: (These are fairly new...but I think I remember getting the same functionality out of CVS...correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dependency which is developed by you along with the main project then subrepos are a perfect fit IMO. I've been using subrepos in these circumstances for a while now and they save a lot of effort. I feel they're particularly beneficial for open-source projects, where getting all dependencies required to build your project can be a pain for someone checking out the code for the firs time: subrepos make this completely automatic.

I can't comment on how easy subrepos are to use if your dependency has its own separate distinct releases and/or is developed by a third party.

Comment: This is what I've found too, but I need something I can prove to my Boss (an ROI).

+1 for a good answer about the value to the programmer though.

Comment: Time saved by a programmer is time they can spend doing something else, so I suppose it's a matter of how much time it takes to set up vs. how much time it saves. The latter is of course a really elusive quantity and convincing one's boss that it's "greater than X" is a tricky thing to do.